# How to read environment variables from YAML file in docker?

Tags: python-3.x, docker, yaml

I'm having a `.env` file that contains variables

```
VALUE_A=10
NAME=SWARNA
```

I'm having an `env.yml` file.

```
Information:
   value: $VALUE_A
   name: $NAME
```

I'm having a python file `envpy.py`

```
from envyaml import EnvYAML

# read file env.yml and parse config
env = EnvYAML('env.yml')

print(env['Information']['value'])

print(env['Information']['name'])
```

Here is my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3
ADD envpy.py /
ADD env.yml /
RUN pip install envyaml
CMD [ "python", "./envpy.py" ]
```

Expected `output`:

```
10
SWARNA
```

But I got :

```
VALUE_A
NAME
```

I'm using the commands to build the docker and run:

```
docker build -t python-env .

docker run python-env
```

How to print the values. Please correct me or suggest me where I'm doing wrong. Thank you.

Comment: How are you launching the container?  Does this setup work without Docker involved?

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze, I mentioned **Dockerfile** and without **docker-compose.yml** it's working as I don't have more services I didn't use it. It's a very small application.

Comment: After you edit the Dockerfile, what is the exact step of `docker` commands you use to build and run the container?  (Please edit the question and include these details there, not in a comment.)  I'm wondering if you have a `docker run --env-file` option, for example.

Comment: Hi @BMitch, I'm a beginner and very confused can you please add an answer so that I can structure it. I have gone through your link and your answer is accepted and if I have code then that helps me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.env` is a docker-compose thing, which defines default values for environment variables to be interpolated into `docker-compose.yml`, and only there. They are not available anywhere else and certainly not inside your image.

You can make the values available as environment variables inside your image by copying `.env` into the image and in your Python code do

```py
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
```

(which requires you to install *dotenv*).

Also mind that there are probably better ways to achieve what you want:

- If the values must be set at build time, you'd rather interpolate them into the resulting file at build time and copy the file with the hardcoded values into the image.
- If the values should be overridable at runtime, just define them via `ENV` with a default value inside the Dockerfile.

Comment: Hi flyx, dotenv is loading environment variables and it's working fine but how to do that same with yaml file as well. I'm having **env.yml** file and need to access those in python. I tried same with above library it didn't work

Comment: `EnvYAML` should pick up the environment variables you loaded via `load_dotenv()`. Does it not?

Comment: It's picking .env file variables and it's fine but I want through **env.yml** file.  Here is the flow. Variables from **.env file -> env.yml -> envpy.py file**

Comment: I am unsure what exactly is not the way you want it. You load the env variables via `load_dotenv()`. Then you load the `env.yml` via `EnvYAML`, which picks up the values that have been loaded by `load_dotenv()` and puts it in their places as specified by `env.yml`.